# how to read a mounted dbc file in databricks?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks, azure-databricks

I try to read a dbc file in databricks (mounted from an s3 bucket)
the file path is:

```
file_location="dbfs:/mnt/airbnb-dataset-ml/dataset/airbnb.dbc"
```

how to read this file using spark?

I tried the code below:

```
df=spark.read.parquet(file_location)
```

But it generates and error:

```
AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for Parquet. It must be specified manually.
```

thanks for help !

Comment: .dbc file - you mean a file with notebooks exported from another workspace?

Comment: Hi @AlexOtt and thanks for your answer ! I think I am confusing the data file with the project file. I imported the .dbc file under databricks workspace and I find it includes two notebooks files and I have no idea when I can find the data file  which is a parquet file).. !

Answer (score -1):

> I tried the code below: `df=spark.read.parquet(file_location)` But it
> generates and error:

You are using `spark.read.parquet` but want to read `dbc` file. It won't work this way.

Don't use `parquet` but use `load`. Give file path with file name (without `.dbc` extension) in `path` parameter and `dbc` in `format` paramter.

Try below code:

`df=spark.read.load(path='<file_path_with_filename>', format='dbc')`

Eg: `df=spark.read.load(path='/mnt/airbnb-dataset-ml/dataset/airbnb', format='dbc')`

Comment: Thanks for your answer  @UtkarshPal-MT!! But it displays "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: dbc. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html" despite that  "display (dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/airbnb-dataset-ml/dataset"))" works well !